# Winforms timer not accurate

Tags: vb.net, winforms, timer

I have an app that uses a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` and am seeing issues with the timer interval.  When I use an interval of 1000 for a duration of 180 seconds the elapsed time is consistently around 183 seconds.  When I use an interval of 995, the elapsed time is accurate (i.e. 180 seconds).  I have tried this on 3 different PCs with the same results on each.  The code below uses 2 textboxes to display the start and end times and a label as a countdown timer.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

```
Public Class Form1

Private WithEvents tmr As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Private Duration As Integer = 180

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    RunTimer()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    lblActivityTimer.Text = FormatCounter(Duration)
    tmr.Interval = 1000

End Sub

Private Sub RunTimer()

    tmr.Start()
    TextBox1.Text = Now.ToString()

End Sub

Private Function FormatCounter(sec As Integer) As String

    Dim Hours, Minutes, Seconds As Integer

    Hours = sec \ 3600
    Seconds = sec Mod 3600
    Minutes = Seconds \ 60
    Seconds = sec Mod 60

    FormatCounter = Hours.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c) & ":" _
                                                    & Minutes.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c) _
                                                    & ":" _
                                                    & Seconds.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c)

End Function

Private Sub tmr_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmr.Tick

    Duration -= 1
    lblActivityTimer.Text = FormatCounter(Duration)
    If Duration = 0 Then
        TextBox2.Text = Now.ToString()
        tmr.Stop()
    End If

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: It is not a high precision timer - the tick events actually rank pretty low in priority so they can happen well after when you expect

Comment: You must be doing a fair bit in your app to be that far off though. It's normally just a few milliseconds late so should be well under a second difference in 3 minutes. The multimedia timer is the best you can do for precision. Here is an example http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?837913-MicroTimer-Resource-Friendly-Accurate-Timer

Comment: I'm just running the code above...nothing else.  It is consistently inaccurate with an interval of 1000 and consistently accurate with an interval of 995.

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue. Start:  `18:41:18`, End: `18:44:18`.

Comment: This is a historic bug in the CLR.  Timers can only expire at the clock interrupt rate.  By default it ticks 64 times per second.  Or once every 15.625 milliseconds.  The CLR calculates how many ticks are needed, but it divides by 15.6, not 15.625.  1000 / 15.6 does not produce 64, the timer actually expires at 65 ticks.  So this adds one more clock tick, you actually get 1015.625 for the interval.  You made it 180 times worse so you'll see 15.625 * 180 = 2.7 extra seconds.  Your workaround of 995 is fine, 995 / 15.6 is 64 ticks.

Comment: Always use the clock to measure *real* elapsed time, it also compensates for any delay in getting your thread re-activated.  The failure mode that nobody tests, goes wrong when the machine is heavily loaded.  Environment.TickCount or DateTime.UtcNow accurately track wall clock time.

Comment: @Hans Thanks for that explanation.  It also coincides with my testing of 998 (which worked) and 999 (which didn't work).  If you want to post as an answer, I'll gladly accept.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Stop Watch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx), it provides a set of methods and properties that you can use to accurately measure elapsed time.

```
Shared Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)
    Dim stopWatch As New Stopwatch()
    stopWatch.Start()
    Thread.Sleep(10000)
    stopWatch.Stop()
    ' Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
    Dim ts As TimeSpan = stopWatch.Elapsed

    ' Format and display the TimeSpan value.
    Dim elapsedTime As String = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10)
    Console.WriteLine( "RunTime " + elapsedTime)

End Sub 'Main
```

Answer (score -1):

There are two readily available Timer object alternatives:

- `System.Threading.Timer` (explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx), my first pick)
- `System.Timers.Timer` (explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx))